# Matched Geometry Effect in SwiftUI is not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm wondering why my `matchedGeometryEffect` isn't working as expected. Did I do something wrong? Because [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93SeJ9ousBw) (at 3:15) did the same and it looks much smoother. Im running the code on a M1 MacBook Air that means the speed is probably not the problem.
Here is my Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var bool = true
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            if bool {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.7)){
                            bool.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "id", in: namespace)
            } else {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "id", in: namespace)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help, Boothosh

Answer (score 4):

In SwiftUI, the modifier order matters. This is the same with [`matchedGeometryEffect(id:in:properties:anchor:isSource:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)).

If you want the rectangles to expand in the center, you need the geometries to align in the center. To do this, we will have `Rectangle`s of the same size. This means that both `Rectangle`s will have the `matchedGeometryEffect` modifier attached, and *then* styled after.

Code:

```
HStack {
    if bool {
        Rectangle()
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "id", in: namespace) // <- Here
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.7)) {
                    bool.toggle()
                }
            }
    } else {
        Rectangle()
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "id", in: namespace) // <- Here
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou I was going crazy.